# PHP How to read XML Child Node Value in a String using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a String which gets its value dynamically from other server.
Value of string is

```
$string1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/xml/namespace/2012/04">
      <Authenticator>AE1001</Authenticator>
    </AuthenticateUserResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

My Question is, generally we use *$xml = simplexml_load_file("test1.xml");* to load XML files, but here in my requirement it is a **String**, how can i read this String value and extract the child node and its value? Example:

`<Authenticator> and its value "AE1001" ?`

Is there a way to put this into Array? so that its easy for me to print out its node value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Also learn [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). It really worth the time.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($string1);

echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('Authenticator')->item(0)->nodeValue; // AE1001
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot man! its short and precise, saves a lot of time! :) Will go through the manuals as you have suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-string.php

http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

This would help you to find a solution for your problem and parse your xml.

Answer (score 0):

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

[DomDocument::loadXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)

both would help you to achieve your task