# How to extract value from xml to php

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ABCD xmlns="http://abcd.com">
<PRODUCT xmlns="">
 <CNHEADER>
  <CNTRACK>true</CNTRACK>
  <FIELD name="PRODUCTNO" value="BK201122"/>
  <FIELD name="ProductType" value="DP"/>
  <FIELD name="strProdCode" value="NL1754"/>
```

Here i want the value of PRODUCTNO and so on.

i tried this but still not getting any output

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // get the url contents 

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request 

curl_close($ch); 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data); 

echo $value = (string) $xml->FIELD[0]->attributes()->name;
```

Comment: Hello Ravi, you should take a look at XML Parser utilities (like SimpleXML) : http://php.net/manual/fr/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP How to read XML Child Node Value in a String using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707040/php-how-to-read-xml-child-node-value-in-a-string-using-php)

Comment: Please do some proper research and make some attempts before posting. There are plenty of guides about reading XML with PHP out there (and here on SO). Try any of those first. If you still can't get it working, you're welcome to come back to show us what you've tried, explain where you're stuck and we can help you from there but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson m here for solution, may be you have the solution then post it here.

Comment: You're just asking for code and SO isn't a free coding service. You're expected to write your own code. We can help you if you get stuck on something _specific_ with your _existing_ code. Please visit [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and read the guidelines.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request

curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

echo $value = (string) $xml->FIELD[0]->attributes()->name;

Comment: i tried this but still not getting any output

Comment: Have you read the comment posted by @Tom Udding? So try that solution and then ask if you have some errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SimpleXMLElement()` you can get your product data from xml string; [ref](http://php.net/manual/fr/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
// Your xml string
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ABCD xmlns="http://abcd.com">
<PRODUCT xmlns="">
 <CNHEADER>
  <CNTRACK>true</CNTRACK>
  <FIELD name="PRODUCTNO" value="Z41346020"/>
  <FIELD name="ProductType" value="DP"/>
  <FIELD name="strProdCode" value="NL1754"/>
 </CNHEADER>
</PRODUCT>
</ABCD>';

$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$productData = [];
foreach ($xmlData->PRODUCT->CNHEADER->FIELD as $productField) {
    $productData[(string)$productField{'name'}] = (string)$productField{'value'};
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($productData);
exit;
```

You will get following output

```
// Output
Array
(
    [PRODUCTNO] => Z41346020
    [ProductType] => DP
    [strProdCode] => NL1754
)
```